# Unique file from multiple data files with diffrent field position

Tags: python

I do have files in different field positions with different fields names that would need to map into a unique file format.

File1: SKU,Qty,UOM,barcode,price,Date

```
   111,12,EA,1234567899,12.50,27/07/2020
```

File2: Itemcode,UOM,Qty,price,bcode,DocumentDate

```
   111,EA,24,12.50,1234567899,27/07/2020
```

Outputfile : Date,SKU,QTY,UOM,barcode,price

```
          27/07/2020,111,12,EA,1234567899,12.50

          27/07/2020,111,24,EA,1234567899,12.50
```

Comment: So, what is the issue here?

Comment: How to do it in Python please?